# Iterate over a collection of function items with generic bounds of associated types

Tags: rust

I'm trying to detect if two square tiles are symmetries of each other, by iterating over the 8 symmetries of the square, applying each of the symmetry transforms to one of the tiles, and comparing the result of that with the other tile.

All of the transforms have the same inputs and outputs. I'd like to loop over them.

I'm using the image crate, which [exports](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/imageops/fn.rotate90.html) the transforms I need, with signatures like this:

```rust
pub fn rotate90<I: GenericImageView>(
    image: &I
) -> ImageBuffer<I::Pixel, Vec<<I::Pixel as Pixel>::Subpixel>> 
where
    I::Pixel: 'static,
```

Note that these include a bound on an associated type; this is making it hard.

This compiles:

```
        for transform in [imageops::rotate90, imageops::rotate180] {}
```

But this doesn't:

```
        for (transform, orientation) in [(imageops::rotate90, Rot90(id)), (imageops::rotate180, Rot180(id))] {
```

```
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn item, found a different fn item
   |
   = note: expected fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r _) -> ImageBuffer<<_ as GenericImageView>::Pixel, std::vec::Vec<<<_ as GenericImageView>::Pixel as image::Pixel>::Subpixel>> {rotate90::<_>}`
              found fn item `for<'r> fn(&'r _) -> ImageBuffer<<_ as GenericImageView>::Pixel, std::vec::Vec<<<_ as GenericImageView>::Pixel as image::Pixel>::Subpixel>> {rotate180::<_>}`
```

..and unfortunately, the second case is actually what I needed to write.

I'm guessing there's some sort of coercion going on that doesn't work when the type of a fn item is used as a type parameter for another type, e.g. of an anonymous tuple type.

I don't feel too strongly about boxing these things into a trait object (although, well, I did just spend about an hour trying to get around it). At this point, I think I'd just be happy with anything that works. But I'm not even sure how to Box these, because how do I spell the type I'm trying to box up?

I'd appreciate any help at all with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the Reference under [Function item types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html) (emphasis added):

> When referred to, a function item, or the constructor of a tuple-like struct or enum variant, yields a zero-sized value of its *function item type*. That type explicitly identifies the function - its name, its type arguments, and its early-bound lifetime arguments (but not its late-bound lifetime arguments, which are only assigned when the function is called) - so the value does not need to contain an actual function pointer, and no indirection is needed when the function is called.
>
> There is no syntax that directly refers to a function item type, but the compiler will display the type as something like `fn(u32) -> i32 {fn_name}` in error messages.
>
> **Because the function item type explicitly identifies the function, the item types of different functions - different items, or the same item with different generics - are distinct, and mixing them will create a type error**:
>
> ```
> fn foo<T>() { }
> let x = &mut foo::<i32>;
> *x = foo::<u32>; //~ ERROR mismatched types
> ```
>
> However, there is a [coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) from function items to [function pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html) with the same signature, which is triggered not only when a function item is used when a function pointer is directly expected, but also when different function item types with the same signature meet in different arms of the same `if` or `match`:
>
> ```
> // `foo_ptr_1` has function pointer type `fn()` here
> let foo_ptr_1: fn() = foo::<i32>;
>
> // ... and so does `foo_ptr_2` - this type-checks.
> let foo_ptr_2 = if want_i32 {
>     foo::<i32>
> } else {
>     foo::<u32>
> };
> ```
>
> All function items implement [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#copy), [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#clone), [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#send), and [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#sync).

In your working example, Rust [LUB coerces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#least-upper-bound-coercions) the function item typed values to function pointers (each element in an array literal is a [coercion site](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites)).  However, in your failing example, Rust is unable to automatically infer that coercion<sup>*</sup> and so you must provide some help to the compiler.  For example, you can:

- [explicitly set the type of the tuple's first element](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2ce7c9031d2432ae9feacfea63fca7f):

  ```
  let transformations: &[(fn(_) -> _, _)] = &[
      (imageops::rotate90, Rot90(id)),
      (imageops::rotate180, Rot180(id)),
  ];

  for (transform, _orientation) in transformations {
      transform(buf);
  }
  ```

or

- [cast the first function item in the array](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c763e4565a2681af6304b96d5ae8841a):

  ```
  let transformations = &[
      (imageops::rotate90 as fn(_) -> _, Rot90(id)),
      (imageops::rotate180, Rot180(id)),
  ];

  for (transform, _orientation) in transformations {
      transform(buf);
  }
  ```

---

<sup>* My reading of the Reference leads me to think this failure to infer the coercion may be a bug, and indeed [there is an open issue about it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74231).</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I spent a long time working through your playground and references. I learned a lot from this, and it did solve my problem.

I agree that this does feel like a bug. The Reference says that tuples are " coercion-propagating expression[s]" https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites which to me reads that (fn_item,) should coerce to (fn_ptr,) by LUB coercion.